# What does mfrow & mfcol stand for in par()?

Tags: r

As the title says. I ask because understanding what the abbreviation stands for helps me remember it and I'm really struggling with this parameter.

If the answer is unintuitive, can you also explain how you rationalize it?

Comment: I always try to avoid `par(mfrow=,mfcol=)`. I find `layout()` to be easier to use and more flexible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Paul Murrell [has listed some helpful mnemonics](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/parMemnonics.html); the interpretation might be

```
 mfrow: number of Multiple Figures (use ROW-wise).
```

Comment: And since no one can remember how to spell mnemonic, he has used parMemnonics as its title.

Answer (score 8):

`mfrow` simply stands for "MultiFrame rowwise layout". The other one is pretty obvious now: `mfcol` stands for `MultiFrame columnwise layout`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing here, and my guess is that it might be "matrix-frame". The parameters set up the row and column dimensions of the graphical device. "mfrow" might be thought of as matrix-frame-by-row, since the two parameters have  The "mfg" parameter might be thought of as matrix-frame-get, since it addresses a location in  matrix-like conceptual arrangement of device splits set up by the last call to par with either "mfcol" or "mfrow".

I suppose another hypothesis might be "-_m_ultiple-_f_igures". Still guessing after an attempt at searching with Google and MarkMail in Rhelp.

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered about this myself. "multi-frame" and "multiple-figures" make all kind of sense.

In the absence of the "right" answer, I came up with the mnemonic "me first" (by) rows and by columns. Certainly wrong, but I always remember what they do!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is : mfrow == matrix filled by row; mfcols == matrix filled by column.