# How are the abbreviations from par function like , mgp, mar, mai deciphered?

Tags: r

How are the abbreviations from `par()` function like, mgp, mar, mai, etc., deciphered? Some of them are intuitive (e.g., lty = line type), but some not. This would help make them easier to remember.

Comment: Type `?par` in the console or read the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html)

Comment: They do seem a little arbitrary at times. My guess is that they also wanted to make every parameter at least three letters long, aside from `bg` and `fg`, which might explain why they'd use `mai` for **m**argin **a**bsolute **i**nches, but `mgp` for **m**ar**g**in **p**osition (instead of `mp`).

From the ones you're asking specifically about, it seems that margins often times start with `m` or `om` (for **o**uter **m**argin).

Comment: That's a question only CRAN members can answer to. Maybe you will find answers if you post the question to [R-Help](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help). But since cross-posting is discouraged include a link to this question.

Comment: Relevant https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/parMemnonics.html

Comment: And relevant SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468174/what-does-mfrow-mfcol-stand-for-in-par

Comment: I'd say that Paul Murrell's list (the stat.auckland.ac.nz link given above) is as close to authoritative and complete as you're going to get.  Maybe someone wants to copy the content into an answer here?

Comment: The links given by @zx8754 are a good answer.

Comment: @BenBolker do you mean to copy the whole table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [table by Paul Murrell](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epaul/R/parMemnonics.html) as shared by @zx8754 in the comments above.

| Parameter | Memnonic |
| --- | --- |
| adj | Text **ADJ**ustment (i.e., justification). |
| ann | Draw plot **ANN**otations? (i.e., labels and titles). |
| ask | **ASK** before starting a new page? |
| bg | **B**ack **G**round colour. |
| bty | **B**ox **TY**pe (what style of box for box() to draw). |
| cex | **C**haracter **EX**pansion factor (text size multiplier). |
| cex.axis cex.lab cex.main cex.sub | cex for **AXIS** tick labels, axis **LAB**els, **MAIN** plot label (title), and plot **SUB**-title. |
| cin | **C**haracter size in **IN**ches. |
| col | Drawing **COL**our. |
| col.axis col.lab col.main col.sub | Drawing colour for **AXIS** tick labels, axis **LAB**els, **MAIN** plot label (title), and plot **SUB**-title. |
| cra | **C**haracter size in **RA**asters (pixels). |
| crt | **C**haracter **R**o**T**ation angle. |
| csi | **C**haracter **SI**ze (height) in inches. |
| cxy | **C**haracter size in **XY** coordinates (relative to the axis scales). |
| din | **D**evice size in **IN**ches. |
| family | Text font **FAMILY**. |
| fg | **F**ore **G**round colour. |
| fig | Size of the **FIG**ure region (as a proportion of the inner region). |
| fin | Size of the **F**igure region in **IN**ches. |
| font | Text **FONT** face. |
| font.axis font.lab font.main font.sub | Text **FONT** face for **AXIS** tick labels, axis **LAB**els, **MAIN** plot label (title), and plot **SUB**-title. |
| lab | Placement of axis **LAB**els. |
| las | Axis **LA**bel **S**tyle |
| lend | **L**ine **END**ing style. |
| lheight | **L**ine **HEIGHT** (multiplier). |
| ljoin | **L**ine **JOIN** style. |
| lmitre | **L**ine **MITRE** limit (when does a pointy line join get beveled). |
| lty | **L**ine **TY**pe (solid, dashed, ...). |
| lwd | **L**ine **W**id **D**th |
| mai | Figure **MA**rgins in **I**nches. |
| mar | Figure **MAR**gins in lines of text. |
| mex | Figure **M**argin character **EX**pansion (multiplier). |
| mfcol | Number of **M**ultiple **F**igures (use **COL**umn-wise). |
| mfg | Specify next figure in **M**ultiple **F**i **G**ure arrangement. |
| mfrow | Number of **M**ultiple **F**igures (use **ROW**-wise). |
| mgp | **M**ar **G**in **P**osition for plot title and axis labels. |
| new | Is the plot region **NEW**? (not been drawn on). |
| oma | Size of the **O**uter **MA**rgins in lines of text. |
| omd | Size of the **O**uter **M**argins as a proportion of the **D**evice (page). |
| omi | Size of the **O**uter **M**argins in **I**nches. |
| pch | **P**lotting **CH**aracter (symbol). |
| pin | Size of the **P**lot region in **IN**ches. |
| plt | Size of the **PL**o**T** region as a proportion of the figure region. |
| ps | Text **P**oint **S**ize. |
| pty | **P**lot **TY**pe (points, lines, both). |
| srt | **S**tring (text) **R**o**T**ation angle. |
| tck | Length of axis **T**i**CK** marks as a proportion of the plot region. |
| tcl | Length of axis **T**i**C**k marks as a proportion of the height of a **L**ine of text. |
| usr | The axis scale ranges (**US**e **R** coordinates). |
| xaxp | **X**-**AX**is tick mark **P**ositions. |
| xaxs | **X**-**AX**is **S**tyle. |
| xaxt | **X**-**AX**is **T**ype. |
| xpd | Bill Venables has proposed "Do you want to e**X**ceed any of the **P**lotting **D**omains?" |
| yaxp | **Y**-**AX**is tick mark **P**ositions. |
| yaxs | **Y**-**AX**is **S**tyle. |
| yaxt | **Y**-**AX**is **T**ype. |